# In d3.js geo map how to create a circle over the each country?

Tags: svg, d3.js, topojson

Am new to `d3.js`.I was created a `world map` with using `json(geojson)` in d3.

Now i want to create a seperate `svg circle` over each `country`.I dont know how to create.Please help any one.I added my fiddle link below.Please take a look and help me.Thanks

My Fiddle Link - http://jsfiddle.net/sam0kqvx/18/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `projection(d3.geo.centroid(d));`:

```
svg.selectAll(".dots")
  .data(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r","6")
  .attr("fill","black")
  .attr("transform",function(d){                 
    var p = projection(d3.geo.centroid(d)); //<-- centroid is the center of the path, projection maps it to pixel positions
    return "translate("+p+")";
  });
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sam0kqvx/33/).

Comment: Hi @Mark.Thanks you so much.You saved my time.Also i have a small doubt.You selected all dots (selectAll(".dots")).Can you tell me what is .dots mean.Sorry am new to d3.js.

Comment: @user3807045, `d3` requires a selector to bind data to it.  That's selecting everything with a class of dot.  In this case it doesn't really do anything, just allows me to bind the data.  My code really should have been `svg.selectAll(".dots").data(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features).enter().append("circle").attr("class","dot")`..., this way you could reselect all your circles if you needed to modify them later.